# Excel VBA: Iterating over range parameter and change cell values

Tags: vba, excel

I believe what I am trying to do is pretty simple. I want to iterate over a Range parameter and change the value for each cell in that range.

```
Function test(thisRange As Range)
    For Each c In thisRange.Cells
         c.Value = 1
    Next
End Function
```

The above is a simple example of what I want to do, but doesn't seem to work. When I debug this, Excel seems to be throwing an error when it hits `c.Value = 1`. Why does this not work?

Comment: It works for me. How are you calling it? Hope not from a worksheet as a UDF?

Comment: Make sure that you declare c as a Range.

Comment: Is there a need to cycle each cell? Can you just use `thisRange.Value = 1`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Why is it an issue to call this function as a UDF?

Comment: A UDF can only change the calling cell

Comment: @ooo My goal is to eventually assign each cell a value dynamically. I just used a static value to simplify the eaxmple.

Comment: @stevebot: Yup as -@ooo rightly said, a UDF cannot change other cells.

Comment: If you want to change multiple cells based on one cell then a worksheet_change event or worksheet_ calculate event may be better

Comment: oh god, I'm an excel idiot. Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ret
    ret = test(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A15"))
End Sub

Function test(thisRange As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In thisRange.Cells
         c.Value = 1
    Next
End Function
```

BTW we don't need to use a Function. A function is used to return a value. Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    test Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A15")
End Sub

Sub test(thisRange As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In thisRange.Cells
         c.Value = 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that does work. Thank you again, I was calling the function as a UDF and that was my issue.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my comment earlier, you cannot use it as a UDF :)